# Python - Web Scraper - Not Picking up Price

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I have coded a (very basic) web scraper to scrape products from sam's club website and then print out the product name and product price.

the problem is that python prints out the same price (the price of the first product on the page) to every single other item (even though the name changes accordingly).

if I change the page to be scraped, the price changes to the first price on that page and then marks that as the price for every single other item.

I dont understand why everything else is working and not the product price?

(sidenote: price variable looks ineleganrt and confusing because sam's clube breaks down their price into 3 fields on the server side.  price = $, price 2 = dollars, price 3 = cents)

Thanks for your help, code is below:

```
import requests, bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#makes each request look like a human request
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'Cookie': 'localeEditionShown_en=true; permutive-session=^%^7B^%^22session_id^%^22^%^3A^%^22e5386dfb-c58a-4882-b0e1-2cc2d9518982^%^22^%^2C^%^22last_updated^%^22^%^3A^%^222017-11-22T19^%^3A10^%^3A04.522Z^%^22^%^7D; visid_incap_774904=4xMirl1lRNOgrnN+Sm9S1zNx61kAAAAAREIPAAAAAACAsmaAAbBYMBjQTCqLf/D6wOVO4hdnKjIF; incap_ses_151_774904=/LX+SNRqsR8SzJi7p3YYAjKgGloAAAAApdQygw8VYBxbv/wvl7Be7A==; _gat=1; _gat_subdomainTracker=1; _ga=GA1.2.1522498341.1508602188; _gid=GA1.2.1243543827.1511694421'
        }

#defines url and requests/beautifulsoup variables
url = "https://www.samsclub.com/s/gatorade"
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
productlist = soup.find_all('div',class_='sc-pc-title-medium')


for products in productlist:
    name = soup.find('div',class_='sc-pc-title-medium').text.strip()
    price = soup.find('span', class_='Price-currency').text.strip()
    price2 = soup.find('span', class_='Price-characteristic').text.strip()
    price3 = soup.find('span', class_='Price-mantissa').text.strip()
    productprice = price + price2 + '.' + price3 #need to find out why its not updating
    
    results = {
        'product name': products.text.strip(),
        'product price': productprice
    }

    
    print(results)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd approach this differently.

Grab all product names and all `span` tags of class `Price-group` and then join them together.

Here's how:

```
import itertools

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.samsclub.com/s/gatorade")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

product_names = [
    p.getText(strip=True) for p
    in soup.find_all("div", class_="sc-pc-title-medium")
]
product_prices = [
    p["title"].split()[-1] for p in soup.find_all("span", class_="Price-group")
]

results = {
    k: v for k, v 
    in itertools.zip_longest(product_names, product_prices, fillvalue="N/A")
}

for product, price in results.items():
    print(product, price)
```

Output:

```
Gatorade Frost Variety Pack (20oz / 24pk) $14.98
Gatorade Sports Drinks Core Variety Pack (12oz / 28pk) $12.78
Gatorade Sports Drinks Liberty Variety Pack (20 oz., 24 pk.) $14.98
Gatorade Zero Variety Pack (12oz / 28pk) $12.78
Gatorade Berry Variety Pack (12 oz., 28 pk.) $12.78
Gatorade Thirst Quencher Powder, Frost Glacier Freeze (76 oz.) $9.98
Gatorade Zero Thirst Quencher Variety Pack (20 oz., 24 pk.) $14.98
Gatorade Powder Lemon-Lime (76.5oz) $9.98
Gatorade Squeeze Bottles (32oz / 3pk) $14.99
Gatorade Medium Classic Cooler (3Gal) $29.98
Selectivend CB500 Gatorade 10 Selection Drink Machine $4,638.00
Gatorade Liberty Variety Pack (12oz / 28pk) $12.78
Gatorade Fierce Variety Pack (20oz / 24pk) $12.98
Gatorade Frost Variety Pack (12oz / 28pk) $12.78
BOLT24 Fueled by Gatorade Variety Pack (16.9oz /15pk) $12.98
Gatorade Fruit Punch (20oz / 24pk) $14.98
Gatorade Lemon-Lime (20 oz., 24 pk.) $14.98
Gatorade Cool Blue (20 oz., 24 pk.) $14.98
Gatorade Orange (20 oz., 24 pk.) $14.98
Gatorade Frost Arctic Blitz (12 fl. oz, 28 pk.) $10.48
Propel Immune Support Zero Sugar Variety Pack (16.9 fl. oz., 24 pk.) $12.98
Gatorade G2 Variety Pack (20oz / 24pk) $12.98
Gatorade Variety Pack (24 oz., 12 pk.) $12.25
Gatorade Cool Blue (32 oz., 12pk.) $12.98
Gatorade Classic Variety Pack (32 oz., 12 pk.) $12.25
Gatorade Orange (32 oz., 12 pk.) $12.25
Gatorade Lemon-Lime (32 oz., 12 pk.) $12.13
Gatorade Fruit Punch (32 oz., 12 pk.) $10.98
Gatorade Fierce Fruit Punch + Berry Thirst Quencher (12oz / 28pk) $10.98
Gatorade Fierce Blue Cherry Thirst Quencher (12oz / 28pk) $10.98
Gatorade Orange Thirst Quencher (12oz / 28pk) $10.98
Gatorade Zero Glacier Freeze Thirst Quencher (12oz / 28pk) $12.25
Gatorade Power Variety Pack (20.83oz / 24pk) $5,748.00
Gatorade Frost Glacier Freeze (32oz / 12pk) N/A
Gatorade All Star Club Variety Pack (24pk/11.83oz) N/A
Gatorade Fruit Punch (20.83oz / 24pk) N/A
Selectivend WS3000/CB300 Gatorade Combo Vending Machine N/A
```

Comment: Awesome, I was thinking of something similiar but I didn't know how to express it in logical terms. Thank you very much for your help!